# Fazer com que alterações em listas sejam locais em Python?

Tags: python

Em Python como eu faço para a função abaixo alterar a lista penas localmente, isto é, apenas no escopo da função `f` sem alterar x definida fora de `f`?

```
x = [1, 2]
def f(x):
    x[1] = "novo valor"
    return x
f(x)

'''
f alterou o valor de x
'''

print x
[1, 'novo valor']
```

Uma solução que encontrei foi a seguinte:

```
def f(x):
    x = x[:]
    x[1] = "novo valor"
    return x
```

Mas isso me pareceu um pouco forçado. Há alguma outra forma?

Comment: Eu estou com um pouco de dificuldade de entender a raiz da sua dúvida. Seria em função de, em Python, os objetos serem passados por referência? (i.e. trata-se do mesmo objeto) Enquanto que em C pode-se também passar objetos/structs por valor (i.e. uma cópia de todos os dados é feita).

Comment: Isso, às vezes quero ter certeza de que a função não vai ter efeitos colaterais, e queria saber as formas de se fazer isso em Python.

Comment: Assim como a maioria das linguagens imperativas orientadas por objetos, não existem muitos recursos para se fazer isso em Python, acaba sendo responsabilidade do programador mesmo... [Essa pergunta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20569142/520779) parece corroborar essa afirmação. Você pode até criar um decorador que faz uma cópia profunda de todos os argumentos de uma função, mas isso não garante contra todos os casos (em particular casos como a função `g` da minha resposta).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é por design. Uma função acessa variáveis no seu escopo léxico mais geral (no caso, o *top-level* do módulo) e pode modificá-las à vontade. Não há qualquer cópia sendo feita. Inclusive essa é a razão pela qual não se deve usar dados mutáveis como parâmetros *default* de funções:

```
>>> def foo(x=[]):
...   x.append('bar')
...   print x
...
>>> foo()
['bar']
>>> foo()
['bar', 'bar']
>>> foo()
['bar', 'bar', 'bar']
```

Se você precisa que dentro de sua função `f` exista uma lista idêntica àquela definida fora no momento da chamada, que você possa modificar à vontade sem interferir na lista original, a única saída é fazer uma cópia mesmo. E sua forma de copiar uma lista está ok.

P.S. Relendo sua pergunta, percebo que isso independe da função acessar uma variável de fora ou não:

```
x = [1, 2]
def f(y):
    y[1] = "novo valor"
    return y
f(x)

def g():
    x[1] = "novo valor"
    return x
g()
```

Sendo o parâmetro mutável, as alterações feitas no mesmo persistirão após o término da função.

---

**Atualização:** se você busca por um modo genérico de copiar argumentos de funções para evitar que os mesmos sejam acidentalmente alterados, uma maneira é criando um decorador que faça uma [cópia profunda](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) de todos os seus argumentos:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> def sem_efeitos_colaterais(f):
...     def ret(*args, **kwargs):
...         args = [deepcopy(x) for x in args]
...         kwargs = { deepcopy(k):deepcopy(v) for k,v in kwargs.items() }
...         return f(*args, **kwargs)
...     return ret
...
>>> @sem_efeitos_colaterais
... def foo(x):
...     x.append(3)
...     return x
...
>>> x = [1,2]
>>> foo(x)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> x
[1, 2]
```

Note que isso só garante contra mudanças nos parâmetros, não contra casos em que a função acessa variáveis no seu escopo léxico mais geral (ex.: a função `g` do exemplo anterior). E, é claro, é bom frisar que fazer cópias de *tudo* tem um impacto negativo no desempenho...

Comment: E há outras formas interessantes/elegantes de fazer essa cópia local do argumento além do `x[:]`?

Comment: @CarlosCinelli Essa aí é a mais "pitônica"... :P (interessante você ter chegado a ela sozinho, a maioria das pessoas usaria uma solução **menos** elegante - como `x = list(x)` por exemplo)

Comment: Valeu, muito boa a edição, esta alternativa pode ser interessante.

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer alterações locais numa lista passada num argumento, você precisa trabalhar sobre uma cópia da mesma.

```
x_local = list(x)
x_local[1] = 'Novo valor'
```