# Como criar objetos imutáveis em Python?

Tags: python

Tomando como base [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33816/fazer-com-que-altera%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-listas-sejam-locais-em-python), é possível criar seus próprios objetos/classes imutáveis em Python, no sentido de que, por default, este meu objeto será copiado ao ser passado como argumento de uma função? Se possível, como fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se isso pode te ajudar!

http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_imut%C3%A1vel#Python

Em Python, alguns tipos embutidos (números, booleanos, strings, tuplas, frozensets) são imutáveis, mas classes personalizadas são geralmente mutáveis. Para simular a imutabilidade em uma classe, deve-se substituir a configuração de atributo e a exclusão para geração de exceções:

```py
class Imutavel(objeto):
    """Uma classe imutável com um único 'valor' de atributo."""
    def __setattr__(self, *args):
        raise TypeError("impossível modificar instância imutável")
    __delattr__ = __setattr__
    def __init__(self, valor):
        # não podemos mais usar self.valor = valor para armazenar dados da instância
        # por isso temos de chamar explicitamente a superclasse
        super(Imutavel, self).__setattr__('valor', valor)`
```

Comment: Para conseguir usar na prática era útil ter também um método que permita copiar o objeto.