# Escrever em ficheiro, substituir palavras/numeros

Tags: python, arquivo

Eu tenho este código que é suposto, ler um ficheiro e apagar todos os números que lá estão, o ficheiro é tipo uma lista de palavras, Ex: *"Ana\n Bruno\n 123\n 10\n ..."*.

Uma linha tem letras ou números, nunca os dois misturados.

O que eu quero é retirar os números, o meu código até agora:

```
foo = open("words.txt", "r+w")

for i in foo:
   i.replace("\n", "")
   try:
      int(i)
   except:
      word = i+ "\n"
      foo.write(word)
```

Comment: O que você tem algo errado no que você quer?

Comment: Simplesmente não faz o que eu quero, não dá error mas tb não retira os numeros

Comment: Você tem que dizer o que você quer ou pelo menos dar detalhes do problema. Está me parecendo que faz o que você quer mas eu posso não ter entendido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem um problema, quando você utiliza o `i.replace(...)` isso realmente não remove as quebras de linha, porque *strings* em [Python são imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33852/como-criar-objetos-imut%C3%A1veis-em-python), o que você quer fazer é:

```
i = i.replace("\n", "")
```

Como você não mencionou mais detalhes sobre o que quer remover, vou supor que não sejam números decimais, mas sim inteiros, para isso você pode usar o método [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) para verificar se a linha atual contem números ou não.

Segue uma implementação com o módulo [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html):

```
import fileinput

for linha in fileinput.input("words.txt", inplace=True):
    linha = linha.replace("\n", "")
    if not linha.isdigit():
        print linha
```

Ver exemplo no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/uTFOOJ).

Em Python 3 equivale:

```
import fileinput

for linha in fileinput.input("words.txt", inplace=True):
    linha = linha.rstrip("\n") # outro modo de retirar a quebra de linha
    if not linha.isdigit():
        print (linha, end = "\n")
```

Ver exemplo no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/PctlPB).

O `fileinput` é um módulo auxiliar na manipulação de arquivos, o `inplace` quando utilizado com o valor `True`, faz com que a saída padrão ([*stdout*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52622/o-que-significa-2-e-em-bash/52624#52624)) seja direcionada para o arquivo de entrada.

Se for necessário trabalhar com números decimais e precisar que seja feito uma cópia do arquivo original, você pode fazer:

```
import fileinput

def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        pass

for linha in fileinput.input("words.txt", backup= ".bak",inplace=True):
    linha = linha.rstrip("\n")
    if not is_number(linha):
        print linha
```

Ver exemplo no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/8nza41).

Um outro modo mais simples que usa o [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) e `isdigit()`:

```
with open('words.txt', 'r+') as f:
    linhas = f.readlines()
    f.truncate(0) # elimina o conteúdo do arquivo

    for linha in linhas:
        linha = linha.rstrip("\n")
        if not linha.isdigit():
            f.write(linha + "\n")
```